# Insertion sort in place LISP

Tags: algorithm, sorting, lisp, common-lisp, insertion-sort

I'm still pretty new to proper Lisp and I'm trying to build a simple, yet  at least a bit efficient insertion sort - I would like to switch elements in place, but still have an ability to append to my container afterwards. I took my old C++ implementation:

```
template<typename Iter>
void insertionSort(Iter begin, Iter end){
    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i){
        for (auto j = i; j != begin && *(std::prev(j)) > *(j); j--){
            std::iter_swap(j, std::prev(j));
        }
    }
}
```

And created the following code (taking into account that `aref` and `rotatef` have fair complexity), but it does not seem to take any effect on the input (UPD: now it simply works improperly), what might be wrong with my solution? I'm returning for testing purposes, should I create a macro in order to avoid pass-by-value?

```
(defparameter testa (make-array 4 :initial-contents '(2 3 1 5)))
(defun insertion-sort (vect)
    (loop for i from 0 to (1- (length vect)) do
        (loop for j from i downto 0
            until (or (= (1- j) -1) (> (aref vect (1- j)) (aref vect j)))
            do (rotatef (aref vect i) (aref vect (1- j))))
    )
    vect
)
(format t "~a~%" (insertion-sort testa))
```

UPD: updated the code based on the comments from @jkiiski and @RainerJoswig, the output is still wrong.

Comment: A `LOOP` with two `FOR`-clauses is just one loop with two variables, not two loops like your C++ version has.

Comment: @jkiiski I've updated the code, the output of the test case is still wrong.

Comment: don't use EQ for comparing numbers. Use EQL or =.

Comment: `(return-from insertion-sort vect)` can be replaced by just `vect`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig the output is still a wrong solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your program there are several problems.

First, the sort does not work since the line:

```
do (rotatef (aref vect i) (aref vect (1- j))))
```

should be:

```
do (rotatef (aref vect j) (aref vect (1- j))))
```

that is, you have written the variable `i` instead of `j`

If you make this correction, you will find that the order is decreasing (I assume that you want an increasing order). This depends on the use of `until` instead of `while`.

Finally, there is redundant code. A more simple and efficient version is the following:

```
(defparameter testa (make-array 4 :initial-contents '(2 3 1 5)))
(defun insertion-sort (vect)
   (loop for i from 1 below (length vect) 
     do (loop for j from i above 0
          while (> (aref vect (1- j)) (aref vect j))
          do (rotatef (aref vect j) (aref vect (1- j)))))
   vect)
(format t "~a~%" (insertion-sort testa))
```

This parallel the pseudo-code in the wikipedia page of [`Insertion sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

If you want to parameterize the sorting predicate, as well as add an optional keyword-based “key” parameter to the function, here is a possible solution:

```
(defun insertion-sort (vect predicate &key (key #'identity))
  (loop for i from 1 below (length vect) 
        do (loop for j from i above 0
                 while (funcall predicate 
                                (funcall key (aref vect (1- j)))
                                (funcall key (aref vect j)))
                 do (rotatef (aref vect j) (aref vect (1- j)))))
         vect)

CL-USER> (insertion-sort testa #'>)
#(1 2 3 5)
CL-USER> (insertion-sort testa #'<)
#(5 3 2 1)

CL-USER> (defparameter testa (make-array 4 :initial-contents '((c 3) (d 2) (b 1) (a 4))))
TESTA
CL-USER> (insertion-sort testa #'string> :key #'car)
#((A 4) (B 1) (C 3) (D 2))
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I extend this function to perform sorting based on a key?

Comment: @MikhailKrassavin: you put a key parameter into the arglist. Then you compare `(> (funcall key (aref ...))  (funcall key (aref ...)) )`.

Comment: @MikhailKrassavin, you are welcome. I’ve update the answer to show the complete solution for the comment of Rainer Joswig.